# Data is showing in console but not displaying in page Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working on Reactjs and using nextjs framework,Right now i am tyring to get
data using axios but data is not showing,But in console.log its showing in getStaticProps section(in blogs),Where i am wrong ?

```
const Post = ({ post, blogs }) => {
 const blogs2 = Array.isArray(blogs) ? blogs : [];
  {blogs2.map((blog) => {
   return <>
                {blog.slug}`}
  </>
  })}
};
export default Post;

export const getStaticProps = async ({ params }) => {
    const { data: data } = await Axios.get(`xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/${params.slug}`);
    const post = data;
    const { data: data2 } = await Axios.get(`xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/${params.slug}`);
    const blogs = data2;
    console.log('data is' +blogs);   //showing data 
    return {
        props: {
            post: post, blogs: blogs
        },
    };
};

export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
    const { data } = await Axios.get("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/blogs");
    const posts = data.slice(0, 10);
   const paths = posts.map((post) => ({ params: { slug: post.slug.toString() } }));

    return {
        paths,
        fallback: true,
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To me this looks like your code actually even has a syntax error and you are missing a return statement. Look at this code;

```
const Post = ({ post, blogs }) => {
 const blogs2 = Array.isArray(blogs) ? blogs : [];
  {blogs2.map((blog) => {
   return <>
                {blog.slug}`}
  </>
  })}
};
export default Post;
```

1. There is an unterminated string literal; the backtick: `
2. The `Post` function doesn't return anything

Maybe you wanted something like this?

```
const Post = ({ post, blogs }) => {
 const blogsArray = Array.isArray(blogs) ? blogs : []
 return blogsArray.map(blog => blog.slug)
}
export default Post
```